# How to arrow toggle up and down by clicked index? Vue

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

How do I rotate just that arrow icon based on the clicked item?

```js
new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    data() {
        return {
            isToggled: false,
            items: [{
                    id: 1,
                    name: "Test1"
                },
                {
                    id: 2,
                    name: "Test2"
                },
                {
                    id: 3,
                    name: "Test3"
                },
                {
                    id: 4,
                    name: "Test4"
                },
            ]
        }
    },
    methods: {
        arrowToggle() {
            this.isToggled = !this.isToggled;
        },
        getItems() {
            return this.items;
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        this.getItems();
    }
});
```

```css
i {
     border: solid black;
     border-width: 0 3px 3px 0;
     display: inline-block;
     padding: 3px;
}
 .down {
     transform: rotate(45deg);
}
 .up {
     transform: rotate(-155deg);
}
 .accordion {
     display: flex;
     background: lightblue;
     align-items: center;
     width: 100%;
     width: 1000px;
     justify-content: space-between;
     height: 30px;
     padding: 0 20px;
}
.arrow {
  transform: rotate(-135deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app" style="display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center;">
        <div v-for="(item, index) in items" :key="index">
            <div class="accordion" @click="arrowToggle()">
               <p> {{ item.name }}</p>
                <i :class="{ 'down': item.isToggled }" class="arrow"> </i>
            </div>
        </div>

 </div>
```

Based on the clicked element do I want my arrow to rotate?
If i have 10 items and click on 2 items i want the icon to rotate there.
Failing to bind id to the clicked item and to bind that class to rotate the item
One thing is very important, I cannot set the isOpen parameter in my json ITEMS which is false which everyone recommends to me. I get it from a database and I don't have a condition for it.

Comment: if other icons are rotated and you clicked on one icon also , those other icons also will rotate to its default poisition ?

Comment: Need to rotate only clicked icon(item). Others no.

Comment: you have to map your data received from server and  attach like isOpen data there.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to arrow toggle up and down? Vue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60328841/how-to-arrow-toggle-up-and-down-vue)

Comment: Yes but i am not got answear.

Answer (score 2):

You will have to toggle at individual item level. Note that I have used `isToggled` per item. Here is full code at: https://jsfiddle.net/kdj62myg/

Even if you get your items from DB, you can iterate through array and add a key named `isToggled` to each item.

HTML

```
<div id="app" style="display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center;">
        <div v-for="(item, index) in items" :key="index">
            <div class="accordion" @click="arrowToggle(item)">
               <p> {{ item.name }}</p>
                <i :class="{ 'down': item.isToggled, 'up': !item.isToggled  }"> </i>
            </div>
        </div>

 </div>
```

Vue

```
new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    data() {
        return {
            isToggled: false,
            items: [{
                    id: 1,
                    name: "Test1",
                    isToggled: false
                },
                {
                    id: 2,
                    name: "Test2",
                    isToggled: false
                },
                {
                    id: 3,
                    name: "Test3",
                    isToggled: false
                },
                {
                    id: 4,
                    name: "Test4",
                    isToggled: false
                },
            ]
        }
    },
    methods: {
        arrowToggle(item) {
            return item.isToggled = !item.isToggled;
        },
        getItems() {
            return this.items;
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        this.getItems();
    }
});
```

Comment: Did you read my question? 
One thing is very important, I cannot set the isOpen (isToggled in your situation) parameter in my json ITEMS which is false which everyone recommends to me. I get it from a database and I don't have a condition for it.

Comment: Yes I did. That is why I have said that even if you get your items from DB, you can iterate through array in JavaScript and add a key named isToggled to each item

Comment: Another option would be to create a separate array with 2 values for each item. Item id and isOpen/isToggled and use this array for switching the button.

Comment: I don't know how do it, because i am posted question.

Answer (score 2):

You have to map your items and attach a custom data on it to solve your problem.

Items data should be like this

```
  items: [{
            id: 1,
            name: "Test1",
            isToggled: false
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            name: "Test2",
            isToggled: false
        },
        {
            id: 3,
            name: "Test3",
            isToggled: false
        },
        {
            id: 4,
            name: "Test4",
            isToggled: false
        },
    ]
```

and your toogle function should look like this.

```
arrowToggle(item) {
    return item.isToggled = !item.isToggled;
},
```

Now, after you fetched the items from the server. You have to map it to attach a isToggled data on every item you have. like this.

```
getItems() {
     axios.get('api/for/items')
    .then(({data}) => {
          this.items = data.map(item => ({
                return {
                    name:item.name,
                    id:item.id,
                    isToggled:false

                }
          }))        
     });
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The above arrowToggle function breaks vue reactivity (google `vue reactivity` for docs). According to the docs, changing an object property directly will break reactivity. To keep reactivity, the function should change to:

```
arrowToggle(item) {
  this.$set(this.item, 'isToggled', item.isToggled = !item.isToggled)
  return item.isToggled;
},
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).